# Getting error as sigabart error on iPhone with the compiled statement

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am preparing sqlite statement and while preparing this statement my code is breaking.I am using following line of code

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,getCC , -1, &getConsumptionCount, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
{

    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare for getConsumptionCount  statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
 }
```

which works perfectly fine on simulator but breaks on iPhone.

My database db.sql was is resource folder which I shifted to other resources folder.
What is the reason why I get SIGABRT error? Like I know it is becoz of NSAssert1 which I put  there but why my application is failing to prepare for the statement.

When I see in the debugger its saying no such table, But I am confused since My database is there and have the table. Is there anything I am doing wrong. How to resolve this.

I am doing it the following way

```
        databaseName = @"CaloriePacerDatabase.sql";
    // Setup some globals

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self openDatabase];
    [self compileStatements];
    return self;
}

- (void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;
    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;
    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem
    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];

}

- (void) openDatabase
{
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to open Database '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
- (void) compileStatements
{
    //int i = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,getCC , -1, &getConsumptionCount, NULL);
    NSLog(databasePath);

    if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,getCC , -1, &getConsumptionCount, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare for getConsumptionCount  statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
```

Please let me know if it is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Are you verifying that the file copy was successful from the resources? Cause there could be an issue and thus you end up with the same new/empty database on [openDatabase].

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, since opening an sqlite3 database by default creates one if it doesn't exist, which could be caused when not properly determining the path between the Simulator and your iPhone.

How are you determining the file path for the database file (db.sql)?

Comment: Hey Nic I updated the question the way I am doing it, I am doing the same way for other apps which is perfectly working fine.